# How do you determine the return type of a method using the ReSharper SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, resharper-7.1, resharper-sdk

I'm trying to write a simple ReSharper 7.1 plugin to change the return type of methods under certain circumstances.

I've derived my class from `ElementProblemAnalyzer<IMethodDeclaration>` and implemented the `Run` method as follows:

```
    protected override void Run(IMethodDeclaration element, ElementProblemAnalyzerData data, IHighlightingConsumer consumer)
    {
            consumer.AddHighlighting(new CustomHighlighting(element), element.TypeUsage.GetDocumentRange(), element.GetContainingFile());   
    }
```

That works well, inasmuch as it highlights the return type of every method. I can't seem to figure out how to check if the return type is `void`, nor can I change the method type from `void` to something else.

I see that the `IMethodDeclaration` interface has a `TypeUsage`, and that it's an instance of `IPreDefinedType`, which in turn implements `IType`, but the ReSharper SDK documentation doesn't explain how you can check the method's return type, nor how to change the return type.

Comment: Is this still actual?

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy I've shelved the idea for the time being, but yes I'm still interested in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a bit and I don't know if you are still looking for the answer. Others may find this helpful as well. You can use something like the following:

```
element.DeclaredElement.ReturnType.GetPresentableName(CSharpLanguage.Instance);
```

Unfortunately I don't quite know how to set the return type.